# Tkinter not importing on windows

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I'm creating a GUI using tkinter but have no experience using it in windows. I followed this documentation: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html
My program folder is connected to a virtual environment that has python3.6 downloaded into it.  I have installed ActiveTcl, ran the test, and it showed I had the correct version of tkinter installed.

in the beginning of the program I have "import tkinter", to which the IDE responds with "unable to resolve "tkinter", IntelliSense may be missing for this module"

I noticed that when I installed activetcl, it created a "tcl" folder outside of my "site-packages" folder(the folder I get all other imports from). The tcl folder holds all of the tkinter libraries but if I "import tcl", it still doesn't work.

Any ideas as to why this could be?

Comment: What is the response _without_ an IDE?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Does the IDE use the same python directory as that of the one you're inspecting?

Comment: It is likely you have a bad install as the windows version of python 3.6 comes with tkinter. Try to uninstall python and then get a fresh copy from python.org and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told to just try this

```
try:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    from tkinter import *
```

Comment: Tried "from tkinter import *" as well as "from Tkinter import *" to no avail. I am using python3.6

Comment: That makes the tkinter code compatible with python 2 and python 3 at once. The OP claims to have python 3 already, so this would only help if the IDE actually uses python 2. However, if that was the case the error that the OP receives would've been an `ImportError` that this code handles.